# Update r_creation_name in documentum through Java using SQL statement

Tags: java, command, documentum

I am trying to execute an SQL statement to update `r_creation_name` in documentum through Java with following code. But it is not updating:

```
 IDfDocument document= (IDfDocument) session.getObjectByQualification(r_object_type+" where orig_doc_id='12345'");

String strSQLQry = "update dm_sysobject_s SET r_creator_name=? "
                                +"where r_object_id=?  ";
                        IDfApplyExecSQL execSQL = (IDfApplyExecSQL) DfAdminCommand.getCommand(IDfAdminCommand.APPLY_EXEC_SQL);
                        execSQL.setQuery(strSQLQry);
                        execSQL.setString("r_creator_name", "Sachin Upadhyay");
                        execSQL.setId("r_object_id", document.getObjectId());
                        execSQL.execute(session);
```

Comment: sachin, I'll look into this. Can you please, in a menatime, provide more details of situation - everything goes smooth but the object isn't updated? if not, is there any exception stacktrace, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing

```
execSQL.setString(1, "Sachin Upadhyay");
execSQL.setId(2, document.getObjectId());
```

Those names are not bound to the parameter placeholders in the statement, which are simple question marks and must be referenced by index.

Comment: its not helping me actually the first parameter requires string, i cant pass integer

Comment: You'll have to provide the code for the class of execSql. if it's part of a Documentum library, then we need a link to the Javadoc